# Using vegetation cover and DEM elevation data together

Tags: qgis, dem, vegetation-index

I'm using Terrain data (DEM) from USGS and I would like to build a map in which I can keep the information on the elevation in 3D and on the vegetation cover. I have obtained the 3D raster for the elevation and I have the shapefile for the vegetation cover but I do not know how to mix them together.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Show both information is a little bit difficult, you have to show which layer will be colored. I would recommend you to convert the DEM to contour and use it with labels or to create a shaded relief and add some transparency to you vegetation cover layer, something like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marco_Lezzerini2/publication/259647616/figure/fig2/AS:297264888205313@1447884880230/Fig-2-Geological-map-of-Easter-Island-Chile-%27%27draped%27%27-on-the-shaded-relief-image.png)

Comment: All solutions are variations of what  @aldo_tapia has proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Mix them how? You have lots of options. You can mix them visually by draping the vegetation data over the DEM, or the hillshade derived from the DEM, and set the transparency of the top layers to build a map that shows both data.  You can create contours from the DEM and set those over the vegetation data.